# Получение и изменение раскладки клавиатуры

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, winapi

Как можно узнать раскладку клавиатуры в определенном окне/процессе и сменить её?

Допустим, открыто стороннее приложение. В зависимости от условий нужно сменить раскладку клавиатуры, их всего две: английская и русская. Что-то вроде такого:

```
if GetLayout() == 'en' and another_condition:
    LoadLayout('ru')
    do_something()
elif GetLayout() == 'ru' and another_condition:
    LoadLayout('en')
    do_something()
```

Написано грубо, но суть ясна: необходимо получить текущую раскладку и сменить её. Подскажите, каким образом это можно сделать? Используется Windows 7 x64.

Нашёл [вот такой ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379713/cant-get-current-keyboard-layout/12383335#12383335), но не смог разобраться в коде на C++.

Comment: С точностью до имён функций и значений id для раскладок клавиатуры, решение выглядит как код в вопросе. [Change keyboard layout with python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1420925/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1420925

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы выполнить задачу необходимо установить дополнительную библиотеку pywin32, которая предоставляет доступ к функциям Windows API из Python. Из этой библиотеки нам понадобится модуль win32api.

```
>>> import win32api
```

Исследовав его содержимое можно увидеть, что для работы с раскладкой клавиатуры есть несколько функций и одно системное сообщение Windows - WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE:

```
GetKeyboardLayout
GetKeyboardLayoutList
LoadKeyboardLayout
```

В данном случае для нас важна именно последняя функция - LoadKeyboardLayout. Данная функция загружает новую раскладку (если она еще не загружена) и предпринимает после этого еще какие-то действия; принимает в качестве аргументов два параметра:

```
строка с идентификатором раскладки.
действие
```

Более подробно о их возможных значениях можно почитать в MSDN. Итак, нам важны две вещи:

```
Получить идентификатор раскладки.
Вторым параметром передать действие переключения на загруженную раскладку.
```

Первый параметр мы можем с легкостью получить из реестра по пути: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Keyboard Layout/Preload`. Итак, выберем переключение на русский язык. В реестре видим примерно следующее:
[image: таблица со значениями в реестре]

Значение записи реестра как раз и будет нужным идентификатором раскладки.
Итак, все, что надо сделать:

```
>>> import win32api
>>> win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout("00000419",1)
```

<sub>[Информация взята из блога Ростислава Дзинько](http://blog.dzinko.org/2010/11/windows.html)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

[Здесь](http://python.su/forum/topic/1946/) описано, как можно определить текущий язык раскладки. Таким образом, метод определения языка раскладки может выглядеть так:

```
import ctypes
      
def get_layout():
    u = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
    pf = getattr(u, "GetKeyboardLayout")
    if hex(pf(0)) == '0x4190419':
        return 'ru'
    if hex(pf(0)) == '0x4090409':
        return 'en'
```

Answer (score 0):

изменить раскладку клавиатуры например на английский:

```
import py_win_keyboard_layout

py_win_keyboard_layout.change_foreground_window_keyboard_layout(0x04090409)
```