# Python Изменение раскладки клавиатуры

Tags: python, windows-10, клавиатура

OC windows 10

для получения раскладки клавиатуры использую функцию
(она работает корректно):

```
import ctypes
def get_layout():
    u = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
    pf = getattr(u, "GetKeyboardLayout")
    if hex(pf(0)) == '0x4190419':
        return 'ru'
    if hex(pf(0)) == '0x4090409':
        return 'en'
```

для изменения на иную раскладку:

```
import py_win_keyboard_layout
# переключение на русскую раскладку
py_win_keyboard_layout.change_foreground_window_keyboard_layout(0x04090419)
# переключение на английскую раскладку
py_win_keyboard_layout.change_foreground_window_keyboard_layout(0x04090409)
```

Переключение на en(0x04090409) происходит верно, но переключение на ру(0x04090419), игнорируется без какой-либо ошибки.

ps. попробовал использовать win32api, опять же команды игнорируются

```
import win32api
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout("00000409", 1)
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout("00000419", 2)
```

Буду крайне признателен за указание ошибки или иной путь решения.
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Где вы взяли вот эти коды 0x4190419?

Comment: У меня подозрение что вы пытаетесь переключится на раскладку которая не установлена.

Comment: из коммеентариев к вопросу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617107/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b?rq=1

Comment: функция get_layout() выдает верный ответ на вопрос какая сейчас раскладка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант.

```
import pyautogui


def switch_keyboard_language():
    pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
    pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
    pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
    pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, решение помогло.

Comment: Я не понимаю почему всплывает панель с языками клавиатуры, так как при переключении руками такого эффекта нет.